# set Padding on TextView programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I am dynamically/programmatically adding TextViews to a preset LinearLayout but for some reason setting padding is not working. Both the text and font appear as expected, but padding doesn't seem to work. Comparing to other solutions online, seems like this should work. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final CustomItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

    holder.Heading.setText(listItem.getHeading());

    ArrayList<String> directions = listItem.getDirections();
    for(int i = 0; i < directions.size(); i++) {
        TextView step = new TextView(context);
        step.setPadding(20, 20, 0, 20);
        step.setText(directions.get(i));
        step.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.lato_light));
        holder.CustomLayout.addView(step);
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public LinearLayout LegLayout;
    public TextView Heading;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Heading = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        LegLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.directionsLayout);

    }

}
```

Comment: It works on my device. If you tested the code on an emulator, please try a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#size-padding-and-margins) say,

> Padding can be used to offset the content of the view by a specific
>   amount of **pixels**

so need to convert dp to px like this:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int paddingPixel = (int) (20 * density);
step.setPadding(paddingPixel, paddingPixel, 0, paddingPixel);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are verifying on high resolution device. You need to use DP to PX conversion and then use that converted value to `setPadding()`;

Method to convert dp to pixel is

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

and your `setPadding` call would be

```
step.setPadding(dpToPx(20), dpToPx(20), 0, dpToPx(20));
```